# Web Config Password Encryption Problem in C# Application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

<add name="connection" connectionString="Data Source=206.65.100.190,1433; Initial Catalog=dvsss; User ID=xxx; Password=234sdf;"

Please help for encrypted password in web config file

It is never a good idea to store the password because it allows all of the project's developers to view the password, and makes fixing the problem extremely difficult.If the account that is protected by the password is compromised, the owners of the system will be forced to choose between security and availability.

Comment: One standard is not to store users' passwords at all but use something like `Trusted_Connection=True;` in the connection string so that privacy would be handled by the network policies

Comment: Do you really use `[c#-4.0]` from 2010 by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the encryption tool available in `aspnet_regiis`:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "c:\path\to\the\folder\containing\webconfig"
```

This will modify the `web.config` file with changes looking similar to this:

```xml
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
          <CipherValue>A long cipher value</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
      </EncryptedKey>
    </KeyInfo>
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>Another cipher value</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

Source: [The ultimate guide to connection strings in web.config](https://blog.elmah.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-connection-strings-in-web-config/#connection-string-encryption)